# jQuery tablesort and .empty() on ajax loaded table keeping rows

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am building a table with ajax and then attaching a jQuery tablesorter (found [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)). This works fine the first time. On a second time (and every one really) I empty out the rows like this:

$('#tblTableName tbody tr').empty();

I then add the rows as I did before and then reattach the tablesorter. It looks fine and I show only the rows that I just added. HOWEVER, if I sort the table it shows the rows that were emptied out (albeit sorted,  `<sarcasm>`YAY! `</sarcasm>`) . I suspect that tablesorter needs to be cleared out as well, but I'm not seeing where to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE

```
$("#YOUR TABLE ID").trigger("update");
```

after adding new rows